# Best way to handle nodejs errors and provide different custom message details

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, custom-errors, custom-error-handling

I have a different groups of errors, for example `MyErrorGroupFoo` and `MyErrorGroupBar` and I want tho handle this errors differently in my error handler, but I also want to provide additional information in error message. The problem is that I distinguish errors by `error.message` so if I want to handle two different types of errors I have to have two error messages like this

```
throw new Error('MyErrorGroupFoo')
```

or

```
throw new Error('MyErrorGroupBar')
```

, but if I want to provide details in error message I have to have many types of error messages, actually almost all error messages will be different like this

```
throw new Error('Wrong Foo, foo =', foo)
```

or

```
throw new Error('Wrong Bar, bar =', bar)
```

How cant I achive goal of handling different groups of errors wit probably (most often) different error messages in particular group?

For now I do it simply by putting JSON to error message like this

```
throw new Error(JSON.stringify({
  what: 'MyErrorGroupFoo',
  why: 'Wrong Foo, foo =', foo
})
```

or

```
throw new Error(JSON.stringify({
  what: 'MyErrorGroupBar',
  why: 'Wrong Bar, bar =', bar
})
```

When I catch the error I parse `error.message` and decide what to do next depending on the `what` property. This approach works well but I feel like there is a better common solution. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Define a class:

```
class ApplicationError {
   constructor(message){
     this.message = message;
   }

   handle(req, res) {
      res.status(500).send(this.message);
   }
}
```

and now for every error that is handled differently than the one in ApplicationError define a new class and throw it when necessary.

```
class EntityNotFoundError extends ApplicationError {
  constructor(message){
    super(message);
  }

  handle(req, res) {
    res.send(404).json({message:this.message})
  }
}
```

and now in your error handler (this defers from framework to framework, the one below can be used for express)

```
app.use(function(err, req, res){
  err.handle(req, res); 
});
```

The main point of this is to have a "interface" in your class that can be standardized. Now you know that every error that comes in has a method that knows how to handle error and send it in the response.

Just be careful as now **all** errors must have handle method. You can bypass that with a simple **if**

```
if (err.handle) {
  err.handle();
} else {
  res.status(500).send();
}
```